# Kafka streams with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to use kafka streams with scala
below is my code in Java which works perfectly fine:

```
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
    KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream("TextLinesTopic");
    textLines.foreach((key,values) -> {
        System.out.println(values);
    });

    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, config);
    streams.start();
```

My scala is code as follows:

```
  val builder = new KStreamBuilder
  val textLines:KStream[String, String]  = builder.stream("TextLinesTopic")
  textLines.foreach((key,value)-> {
   println(key)
  })

  val streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, config)
  streams.start()
```

The scala code throws compilation error. Type mismatch expected:ForEachAction[*>String,*>String],Actual((any,any), Unit)
not found:value key
not found: value value

Does anyone know how to use streams API in scala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong :). `->` is just operator for creating pairs, so expression

```
(key,value)-> {
  println(key)
}
```

Has type ((Any, Any), Unit) because compiler cannot infer any type information (and `key` and `value` are missing)

If you are using scala 2.12 replacing `->` with `=>` should solve the problem, but if you are using older version of scala, you will have to implement java bifunction explicitly:

```
 textLines.foreach(new BiFunction[T1, T2] { ... })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly print kafkastream using print method.

> textlines.print

It will print the  kafka stream. You can even print either key or values by passing argument to print function.